# AWS RDS Postgresql Password validation

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, amazon-rds, eventtrigger

SOX compliance raised questions on accounts created into Postgresql Database As AWS RDS.

1. Password are not expired -- We can get the password expired by setting until option.
2. Password complexity (forcefully push users to change password with compliance policy  Like password leangth,Upper & lowner case including numeric values with special characters etc.).

How can we achieve this ?
Any example of Password function, Trigger on alter user password statement which will raise exception and abort the statement if Password complexity requirement doesn't met.

Need help not good with coding stuff.

Comment: Rather than having static passwords, you could [Use IAM authentication to generate database user credentials - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-user-credentials.html). That way, it can take advantage of IAM credential rotation and complexity, but it would change the way that users (or apps) connect to the database.